# How to display an image represented by three matrices in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I have 3 matrices (R G B) in double precision format, so all I need is OpenCV version of matlab [cat](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/ref/cat.html) function to display image. If you have any sources or references please post, I would be grateful.

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`merge()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#merge) for such tasks. I'm assuming that you're using C++ for the following example code, but this function is available for C and Python too (see docs).

```
// Suppose you have 3 matrices (instances of class cv::Mat)
// named channelR, channelG and channelB that hold your data
std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
channels.push_back(channelR);
channels.push_back(channelG);
channels.push_back(channelB);

cv::Mat outputImage;
merge(channels, outputImage);
```